# Textbox css with info

Tags: html, css, textbox

I want to create a textbox for the username But once he starts typing i need a small image with the requirements of username to be displayed dynamically ..

can anyone help me ??

Comment: Why an image?  Why not display text describing the requirements of the username?  Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say A1 is your text box and X1 is your image:

```
<script>
    function txtChange(){
        a1=document.getElementById(a1);
        x1=document.getElementById(x1);
        if(a1.value.length>0) {
           x1.style['display'] = true;
        }
    }
</script>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a1.Attributes["onchange"] = "txtChange()";
}
```

Oh and I guess it's worth mentioning if you want it just when they focus (click on it) not when they add text you can change "`onchange`" to "`onfocus`"

Comment: I'm confused, did you just use a Javascript variable inside your C# code?

Comment: No, the lines 'a1=document.getElementById(a1);' and 'x1=document.getElementById(x1);' make 'a1' and 'x1' reference C# controls (in this case textbox and image).

Comment: How does this do it with css and html?? This is a javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :focus psuedo class on the textbox to add styling when the box has focus.

You cannot do what you are asking without javascript though.

Comment: He *might* be able to do this  using `:focus` and `:after` but it's not a clean solution. JS is needed

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the location of the image, can you do something like this:

html

```
<input class="my_textbox"><img src=""/>
```

and then, using ":focus" and css sibling selector:

css

```
input.my_textbox + img {
  display:none;
}
input.my_textbox:focus + img {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: please tell me you did not put an image inside a textbox.... that is just wrong!!

Comment: err no, it's a sibling selector... The <img> tag is not inside the input. It's AFTER the input element.